# Am I need to clear Hibernate exception somehow?

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, transactions

I am doing exception check while saving data in the following way:

```
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(person);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        log.error("Error saving person to database", e);
    }
```

nevertheless I have my application terminated with an exception somewhere later.

(I did this check in order to avoid of Data truncation errors. May be there is a way to check data truncation without causing an exception in Hibernate?)

Comment: What was the other exception that causes your application to terminate? Post the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a Hibernate exception is thrown, you cannot use the session, which caused the exception, any more. A rollback is done automatically.

If you want to continue after the exception, you have two possibilities:

1. Throw away the old session and create a new one.
2. Use a StatelessSession instead of a session. A StatelessSession can be used after an exception. In a StatelessSession you have to do the rollback manually.

Normally you'll do solution 1.

Solution 2. is useful if you intentionally provoke an exception and you have a special way to react on it. (For example an index violation exception in an insert operation, and after the exception you do an update instead of an insert.)